# How to get Forward price based on Put-Call parity?

Tags: option-pricing, put-call-parity

Could you advise how to find a forward price using Call/Put (+Spot and Strike) ? Investodepia says that forward is equal to option's strike based on Put-Call Parity but it seems to me there is a formula to extract a forward price from call/put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call minus Put = forward

Which means call price minus put price equals current price of a forward, all same strike and maturity.

Comment: Thank you very much! Am right that minus Put together with Call give us a line in a graph of possible outcomes?

Comment: Indeed. Minus  \\_ + _/ .The minus flips the first stick around the x axis so you get a long line (/) graph.